# div layout problems. resolution

Tags: css, html

Okay i have this problem with every page i make. im not sure what im doing wrong but all my pages never work for every resolution. Probably because im using a widescreen? lol im not sure but it never looks right on resolutions smaller than a widescreen one. parts of it you cant see so you have to scroll to the side or in this case the content extends furthur than the div. an example is at [larzconwell.com](http://larzconwell.com)

so heres the code. i would greatly appreciate it if you could help me resolve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tinos' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">     </script>
<title>Larz Conwell</title>
<style>
/* standard */
body {
    background-color: #333;
color: #ccc;
font-family: 'Tinos', arial, serif;
}
a:link {
color: #CCC;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #CCC;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #09F;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #09F;
}
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
/* classes */
.dash {
font-size:20px;
color:#09F;
}
.header {
z-index:1;
float:left;
background:#666;
margin-left:25px;
margin-top:75px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
width:31%;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
opacity:0.9;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90);
}
.menu {
z-index:3;
float:right;
background:#666;
margin-left:25px; /*only applies if floating left */
margin-right:25px;
margin-top:15px;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:5px;
width:27%;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
opacity:0.7;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
.menuname {
color:#09F;
font-size:20px;
}
.content {
z-index:2;
float:left;
background:#666;
margin-left:25px; /*only applies if floating left */
margin-right:25px;
margin-top:50px;
padding-top:25px;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-bottom:25px;
width:60%;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
opacity:0.7;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
 }

.linkletter {
color: #09F !important;
font-size:50px !important;
}
.linkletter:hover {
color:#000 !important;
font-size:50px !important;
}
.links {
font-size:35px !important;
}
.links:hover {
font-size:35px !important;
color:#000 !important;
}
.footer {
z-index:2;
float:left;
background:#666;
margin-left:25px; /*only applies if floating left */
margin-right:25px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:10px;
width:31%;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;
opacity:0.7;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
</style>
<!--disables rightclick-->
<script language=JavaScript>
<!--

//Disable right mouse click Script
//By Maximus (maximus@nsimail.com) w/ mods by DynamicDrive
//For full source code, visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com

 var message="Function Not Allowed -Larz Conwell";

///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")

// --> 
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('div').hide().fadeIn(3500);
  $(".header").draggable();
 });  
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu").draggable();
 }); 
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").draggable();
 }); 
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".footer").draggable();
  }); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--header area: logo-->
<div class="header">
<p><img src="images/logo.png" width="437" height="158" alt="Larz Conwell" /></p>
<p><span class="dash">//</span>Web Designer & Graphic Artist</p>
</div>
<!-- menus-->
<div class="menu">
<p>Note right now the Portfolio portion of the website does not work and is in      progress.</p>
  <p class="menuname">  //Portfolio</p>
<p><span class="dash">//</span><a href="pages/photography.html">Photography</a>   &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="dash">//</span><a href="pages/photoshop.html">Photoshop  Creations</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="dash">//</span><a href="pages/design.html">Designs</a></p>
</div>
<!--content-->
<div class="content">
 <table width="100%" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="36%" valign="top"><img src="images/about.png" width="251" height="81" alt="About" /><br />
  Hello I'm Larz Conwell and i reside in Georgia, I am a Freelance Web Designer and Graphic Artist. As of right now i am a senior in high school and i am working on getting better at Web Design as well as Graphic Design. If you would like a web site made or editing done please ask i would love to help, and since im only in high school, for now im doing anything for free. <br /></td>
  <td width="23%" valign="top"><img src="images/contact.png" width="251" height="81" alt="Contact" />
    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="/cgi-bin/cgiemail" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="32" align="right" valign="top">Name</td>
          <td valign="top"><label for="name"></label>
          <input name="name" type="text" id="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="31" align="right" valign="top">E-mail</td>
          <td valign="top"><label for="email"></label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30" align="right" valign="top">Comment</td>
          <td valign="top"><label for="comment"></label>
            <label for="comment"></label>
          <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="21" rows="5"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Me" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </form></td>
  <td width="41%" valign="top"><img src="images/qa.png" width="251" height="81" alt="Questions &amp; Answers" /><br />
    Q: Why should i pick you to make my website?<br />
    A: I am able to make your website however you want and i have good design techniques so it will look great and also have great functionality at the same time.<br />
    <br />
    Q: Why would you make content for people for free?<br />
    A: Mainly because im in high school and i dont have &quot;proper&quot; training, so i feel i should do it for free till i get out of college. Plus, who doesnt like free stuff?    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="center"><span class="linkletter">F</span><a href="http://facebook.com/larz.conwell"><span class="links">acebook</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="linkletter">E</span><a href="mailto:larzconwell@gmail.com"><span class="links">-mail</span></a></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<!--footer-->
<div class="footer"><span class="dash">//</span>&copy;2011 All Rights Reserved Larz Conwell &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:larzconwell@gmail.com">E-mail</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance (:

Comment: widescreen? can you post a screenshot? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each of your div elements you have a percentage width set, which means that when the browser window is less than a certain width, then your divs will resize as well and the content of the divs will fall out. This can be resolved by replacing the percentage width with a pixel value, you could try this:
**Correct:**

- width:360px;

**Incorrect (results in browser resize issues):**

- width:30%;

Comment: your sure that will work? i usually use px sizing and it doesnt work for me either but i will try thank you

Comment: It will work! if it doesn't come to me with that problem as well and I would gladly resolve it for you. Glad to be of some help!

Comment: what would be a good px size for aligning to the left? for all resolutions i mean lol 360 sounds pretty big.

Comment: To begin with I would put a div as a child of your body element give it a min-width and a min height so that when you resize the window your four divs aren't jumping around

Comment: I will provide an example of your site improved on my site wait a minute and I will give you a link.

Comment: You should seriously look into external css style sheets. It make web developing so much simpler.

Comment: And also you should look into margin and padding shorthand properties for CSS.

Comment: i got it working right thank you lol i will look in to the shorthand propertie things.

Comment: oh yeah i know about the shorthand properties but it confuses me a little and i cant remember which value is for which side lol

Comment: Check this out and compare it to your site. Resize the two to see the difference and copy the source of mine. http://munchpost.com/experimental/your%20site%20improved

Answer (score 0):

Every designer face this problems,
I would suggest you to make 2 css files, one for resoulution 800X1024 and another for wide,
and write a code to detect the resolution and output the required CSS,
try this out and see

I am not sure but try this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getcss(cssfile){

loadcss = document.createElement('link')

loadcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")

loadcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css")

loadcss.setAttribute("href", cssfile)

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadcss)

}

if(screen.width <= '800')
// Defines the resolution range you're targeting (less than 800 pixels wide in this case)

{

getcss('800x600.css')
// Defines the .css file you want to load for this range (800x600.css)

}



else if(screen.width > '800' && screen.width < '1280')
// This time we're targeting all resolutions between 800 and 1280 pixels wide

{

getcss('1024x768.css')
//And we want to load the .css file named "1024x768.css"

}


else if(screen.width > '1024' && screen.width < '1600')
//Targeting screen resolutions between 1024 and 1600px wide

{

getcss('1280x1024.css')
//Load 1280x1024.css

}



else

{

getcss('1280x1024.css')
//This else statement has "if" condition. If none of the following criteria are met, load 1280x1024.css

}

</script>
```

Comment: AHH that sounds like a great idea. thank you thank you thank you

Comment: I am sorry but this is not a very efficient way to resolve the problem. You can just set the width of the divs to a pixel value instead of a percentage value and your problem is resolved.